# How to avoid memory error when computing huge covariance and identity matrices with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices as numpy arrays:

```
A.shape
(800, 1200)
B.shape
(800, 101343)
```

I need to compute the covariance matrix of A, and B, and the identity matrix of A and B:

```
import numpy as np
a_row, a_col = A.shape
b_row, b_col = B.shape
C_ab = np.cov(A,B, rowvar=False)[:a_col, a_col:]
ai = np.eye(a_col)
bi = np.eye(b_col)
```

The problem here though is that I  get:

```
   2493     else:
   2494         X_T = (X*w).T
-> 2495     c = dot(X, X_T.conj())
   2496     c *= 1. / np.float64(fact)
   2497     return c.squeeze()

MemoryError:
```

Because of the size of `B`. Anyone know of a work around?

Answer (score 1):

GraphLab create has their own implementation of Numpy that you can install, that does all the computation on disk, see: https://turi.com/learn/gallery/notebooks/linear_regression_benchmark.html. Specifically they have a command:

```
import numpy as np
import graphlab.numpy
```

which results in:

```
Scalable Numpy Activation Successful
```

After that Numpy should be able to handle your matrix.

Comment: if I manage to get this to work so that I can test it, I will accept the answer, as it stands, any attempt to use numpy after `import graphlab.numpy` results in a `Access to invalid address: 0xffffffffffffffff
Aborted` in ipython and `Access to invalid address: 0xffffffffffffffff
kernel died, restart ([y]/n)?` in jupyter-console

Comment: @atomsmasher This might be a nuisance, but I suggest you to update your Python 2 to the latest 2.7.10. It looks like python was trying to access a memory location it was not supposed to.

Comment: output from `python --version Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)` did a few tests: all of these work fine : `np.eye(10)`, `np.eye(100)`, `np.eye(1000)`, `np.eye(10000)`. it's only at `np.eye(100000)` that the error appears

Comment: Try setting a larger memory: graphlab.numpy.set_memory_limit(limit). You can use graphlab.numpy.get_memory_limit() to see how much it the max memory usage. Although, I don't think this will fix your issue. There *might* be some bug that you are encountering. Hence I think this solution isn't valid : (

Comment: Just as a note, I increased my memory to 2065694720*2 (4.13138944 gigabytes), and it takes np.eye(100000).

Comment: yea, that didn't fix it. I'm going to try it on a different machine. for what it's worth, I also installed it with pip.